# How to optimize reversing the order of groups of bits

Tags: c, mips

Basically, I have 8 pieces of data, 2 bits each (4 states), being stored in the 16 LSBs of a 32-bit integer. I want to reverse the order of the data pieces to do some pattern matching.

I am given a reference integer and 8 candidates, and I need to match one of the candidates to the reference. However, the matching candidate may be transformed in some predictable way.

If the reference data is in the form [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], then the possible matches can be in one of these 8 forms:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [0,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
[6,7,0,1,2,3,4,5], [2,1,0,7,6,5,4,3]
[4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3], [4,3,2,1,0,7,6,5]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1], [6,5,4,3,2,1,0,7]
```

The pattern is that the data is always in order, but can be reversed and rotated.

I am implementing this in C and MIPS. I have both working, but they seem bulky. My current approach is to mask each piece from the original, shift it to its new position, and OR it with the new variable (initialized to 0).

I did more hard coding in C:

```
int ref = 4941; // reference value, original order [1,3,0,1,3,0,1,0], (encoded as 0b0001001101001101)
int rev = 0;
rev |= ((ref & 0x0003) << 14) | ((ref & 0x000C) << 10) | ((ref & 0x0030) << 6) | ((ref & 0x00C0) << 2); // move bottom 8 bits to top
rev |= ((ref & 0xC000) >> 14) | ((ref & 0x3000) >> 10) | ((ref & 0x0C00) >> 6) | ((ref & 0x0300) >> 2); // move top 8 bits to bottom
// rev = 29124 reversed order [0,1,0,3,1,0,3,1], (0b0111000111000100)
```

I implemented a loop in MIPS to try to reduce the static instructions:

```
        lw      $01, Reference($00) # load reference value
        addi    $04, $00, 4         # initialize $04 as Loop counter
        addi    $05, $00, 14            # initialize $05 to hold shift value
        addi    $06, $00, 3         # initialize $06 to hold mask (one piece of data)

# Reverse the order of data in Reference and store it in $02
Loop:   addi    $04, $04, -1            # decrement Loop counter
        and     $03, $01, $06       # mask out one piece ($03 = Reference & $06) 
        sllv    $03, $03, $05       # shift piece to new position ($03 <<= $05)
        or      $02, $02, $03       # put piece into $02 ($02 |= $03)
        sllv    $06, $06, $05       # shift mask for next piece
        and     $03, $01, $06       # mask out next piece (#03 = Reference & $06)
        srlv    $03, $03, $05       # shift piece to new position ($03 >>= $05)
        or      $02, $02, $03       # put new piece into $02 ($02 |= $03)
        srlv    $06, $06, $05       # shift mask back
        addi    $05, $05, -4            # decrease shift amount by 4
        sll     $06, $06, 2         # shift mask for next loop
        bne     $04, $00, Loop      # keep looping while $04 != 0
```

Is there a way to implement this that is simpler or at least fewer instructions?

Comment: Nicely asked question, but might get a better response from [one of the places suggested here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165521/236796)_.

Comment: This sort of optimization can be highly dependent on context. If you have many reference integers to match with 8 fixed candidates, there may be a useful approach that is not available generally. Or if you have one reference integer to match with various sets of 8 candidates, there may be another approach. If there are many matches to do at one time, that can affect the approach. If a fair amount of other work must be done in between matches, that can affect it. To start, why do you believe this needs optimization? Has it proven to be a bottleneck in your code?

Comment: When you write “I am given a reference integer and 8 candidates,” are the eight candidates the eight variations on the data arrangement, or are there eight original candidates each with the eight variations?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am given 8 candidates, one of which is some transformation of the reference. So one of the candidates will be one of the 8 forms of the reference, while the other seven candidates will be random data.

Comment: The transformations of the reference can be prepared in advance, so that, when any candidates arrive, they merely need to be compared to the precomputed transformations, and no rotations or reversals need to be performed at the time that candidates are evaluated.

Comment: @Jackson: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote those that helped you.

Comment: @chqrlie whoops my bad. should be there now.

Comment: just use [`__builtin_bitreverse8/16/32/64` intrinsics](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) if you're using Clang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse your bits, you can use the following code.

```
static int rev(int v){
  // swap adjacent pairs of bits
  v = ((v >> 2) & 0x3333) | ((v & 0x3333) << 2);
  // swap nibbles
  v = ((v >> 4) & 0x0f0f) | ((v & 0x0f0f) << 4);
  // swap bytes
  v = ((v >> 8) & 0x00ff) | ((v & 0x00ff) << 8);
  return v;
}
```

MIPS implementation is 15 instructions.

```
rev: # value to reverse in $01
     # uses $02 reg
   srli $02, $01, 2
   andi $02, $02, 0x3333
   andi $01, $01, 0x3333
   slli $01, $01, 2
   or   $01, $01, $02
   srli $02, $01, 4
   andi $02, $02, 0x0f0f
   andi $01, $01, 0x0f0f
   slli $01, $01, 4
   or   $01, $01, $02
   srli $02, $01, 8
   andi $02, $02, 0xff
   andi $01, $01, 0xff
   slli $01, $01, 8
   or   $01, $01, $02
   # result in $01
```

Note that you can simultaneously reverse 2x16bits by just doubling the constants (and even 4 on 64 bits machines). But I am not sure it is useful in you case.

Comment: The MIPS code has the `slli` and `srli` swapped, but other than that it works. Thank you!

Comment: Fixed the `slli` and `srli`swap. Thanks for signalling the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple and effective approach, use a 256-byte lookup table and perform 2 lookups:

```
extern unsigned char const xtable[256];

unsigned int ref = 4149;
unsigned int rev = (xtable[ref & 0xFF] << 8) | xtable[ref >> 8];
```

The `xtable` array can be initialized statically via a set of macros:

```
#define S(x)  ((((x) & 0x0003) << 14) | (((x) & 0x000C) << 10) | \
               (((x) & 0x0030) <<  6) | (((x) & 0x00C0) <<  2) | \
               (((x) & 0xC000) >> 14) | (((x) & 0x3000) >> 10) | \
               (((x) & 0x0C00) >>  6) | (((x) & 0x0300) >>  2))
#define X8(m,n)   m((n)+0), m((n)+1), m((n)+2), m((n)+3), \
                  m((n)+4), m((n)+5), m((n)+6), m((n)+7)
#define X32(m,n)  X8(m,(n)), X8(m,(n)+8), X8(m,(n)+16), X8(m,(n)+24)

unsigned char const xtable[256] = {
    X32(S,   0), X32(S,  32), X32(S,  64), X32(S,  96),
    X32(S, 128), X32(S, 160), X32(S, 192), X32(S, 224),
};

#undef S
#undef X8
#undef X32
```

If space is not expensive, you could use a single lookup into a 128K-byte table, which you would compute at startup time or generate with a script and include at compile time, but it is somewhat wasteful and not cache-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Note: *Be-careful with handwritten optimized assembly, there are really processor specific optimization keep them if you really have a strugle with your compiler generation in a tight loop*.

You can improve the [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining), (if you code in C the compiler do it for you) and use the delay slot of the `bne` instruction. This will improve your [instruction level parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism).

Assuming you have something like a Mips Processor with a 1 delay slot and 5 stage pipeline (Instruction Fetch, Decode, Execute, Memory, Writeback).

This pipeline introduce [Read After Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)) Hazards on data dependence most were on `$3` register.

A RaW hasard cause your pipeline to stall.

```
# Reverse the order of data in Reference and store it in $02
Loop:   and     $03, $01, $06       # mask out one piece ($03 = Reference & $06)
        addi    $04, $04, -1        # decrement Loop counter (RaW on $3)
        sllv    $03, $03, $05       # shift piece to new position ($03 <<= $05)
        sllv    $06, $06, $05       # shift mask for next piece
        or      $02, $02, $03       # put piece into $02 ($02 |= $03)
        and     $03, $01, $06       # mask out next piece (#03 = Reference & $06)
        srlv    $06, $06, $05       # shift mask back
        srlv    $03, $03, $05       # shift piece to new position ($03 >>= $05)
        addi    $05, $05, -4        # decrease shift amount by 4
        or      $02, $02, $03       # put new piece into $02 ($02 |= $03)
        bne     $04, $00, Loop      # keep looping while $04 != 0
        sll     $06, $06, 2         # shift mask for next loop
```

If you have a Superscalar processor the solution need some changes.

Comment: The code need a review because assembly hand optimization always need so! :)